# Boxes stacked one above the other

Tags: logical-deduction

> Eight boxes, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H are kept one above another not necessarily in the order above.
>
> - Three boxes are between H and G and neither of them is at the top or bottom
>     position.
> - Two boxes are between F and C and box F is above box C.
> - Two boxes are between G and C.
> - The number of boxes between A and H is same as the number between A and G.
> - Box D is above box E and more than one box is between D and E.
> - Box E is not at the bottom position.
>
> [Source](https://gradeup.co/liveData/f/2018/5/Puzzle_English%20Part.pdf-37.pdf)

Is the answer to the above question:

```
F  
D  
H  
C  
A  
E  
G  
B
```

Comment: Yeah! that's the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yes, I believe that this is the only solution.  My reasoning, which I'm sure is what you had, but to reaffirm:

Reasoning (note: Top->Bottom, (#) is the clue sentence):

> Using clues (2) and (3), the only options are _F__C__G or F__C__G_.  Since G is not the bottom (1), it's the latter.

Then it follows:

> H must be 3 above G (1): F_HC__G_.  A must be (4) F_HCA_G_. Based on (5 & 6): FDHCAEG_

And finally:

> FDHCAEGB (the only possible answer)

Answer (score -1):

> D  4.
>  G  1.      3.
>  B
>  A  3.
>  F  2.
>  H  1.      3.
>  E  4.
>  C  2.
>
>  There may be more possible solutions. The numbers point to the hints given!
>
>  B was not mentioned, so I left B at an empty place.

Comment: Hi Anders, welcome to Puzzling!  Please hide your answer using the spoiler tag (">!").  Also, can you clarify your answer and expand on your logic, please? I'm having a hard time reading it in the current format and I'm unsure how you reached all of your conclusions (for example, G and C should have 2 boxes between them, but your answer seems to have 5 between them).  Thanks and happy puzzling!